# How to use "editor" field type in joomla "repeatable" form field?

Tags: ckeditor, field, joomla3.0

I am developing a module for Joomla 3.3.6. I want to use "editor" field type in "repeatable" field in the xml file. The code I am using is as follows:

```
             <field 
                name="fpssibtos_img1subs"
                type="Repeatable"
                icon="list"
                label="GLOBAL_SUBS"
                description="GLOBAL_SUBS_DESC"
                default="{'fpssibtos_img1sub':['test']}">
                <fields name="params">
                    <fieldset hidden="true" name="fpssibtos_img1subs_modal" repeat="true">
                        <field 
                        name="fpssibtos_img1sub"
                        default="test"
                        type="editor"  
                        label="GLOBAL_SUB" 
                        description="GLOBAL_SUB_DESC"  
                        filter="safehtml"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </fields>
            </field>
```

The problem is the editor is not editable, I mean you cannot type anything in it.
[image: editor appears but it is not editable.]
I am using CKEditor, I changed it to TinyMCE and others ,but the problem persists. I know that repeatable form field is still buggy ,but I thought some of you guys might know the fix to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this problem, the repeatable form fields only support simple field types. This is apparently due to Joomla not having a simple way for scripts to interact.

Comment on the issue from one of the devs [here](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/3574#event-25185) and [here](http://1%20-%20fix%20locally,%20on%20my%20PC,%20as%20I%20said%20I%20still%20not%20made%20PR%20:)%202%20-%20ok,%20currently%20Repeatable%20supports%20only%20simple%20fields,%20if%20the%20field%20have%20a%20additional%20JS%20logic%20(like%20editor,%20media%20and%20couple%20other),%20then%20it%20will%20be%20broken%20for%20100%25%20...%20currently%20Joomla!%20have%20no%20API%20for%20interaction%20between%20scripts,%20there%20old%20pull%20#1260%20...%20but%20looks%20like%20no%20chance%20that%20it%20will%20be%20finished%20some%20day%203%20-%20scroll%20-%20is%20good%20idea,%20will%20see).